# Does a switched on power socket consume electricity?

Tags: electricity, voltage, power

Lets say I have a TV and a power socket but the TV switch is off however the socket switch is switched on, so will it consume electricity?

Comment: What does "consume electricity" mean? Are you asking whether there is consumption of *power*?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the TV.

An old TV with a real physical switch wouldn't consume any power, there is a break in the circuit and whether that break is at a switch on the socket or a switch in the TV makes no difference.

Even a slightly more modern TV with an electronic power switch would consume "almost" no power - the electronic switch would leak a tiny amount of power when off, because the silicon switch is slightly more conductive than the air gap in a physical switch.

What a very modern TV, stuffed full of computers, does when you turn it off is unknown.  It could have circuits still active waiting for a signal from an infrared remote, or be checking the internet for updates, or even downloading shows while it sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer is right.

I would like to add some points here though. 
In the old TV's we used to get electric shocks(huge ones) when we used to touch the circuit of TV even when the socket was off. 
Some people think this is because the TV set is using the electric current, even when the tv is off. 
But, something worth mentioning here is, the shock used to only time only i.e it happened only once if the Tv off and the circuit was touched, after that if the circuit was touched again, nothing used to happen.
This was not because, the TV was still using electricity, this used to be because of the tremendous amount of charge left in the capacitors.